# Getting "Internal Error (check logs) " in Play framework 1.2.5

Tags: java, playframework-1.x

Natty server is throwing HTTP 500 error while requesting for html resource for second time! can any one provide me the solution?

here is my code snippet.

```
onClick="window.open('/public/html/index.html', '_blank')
```

the above html(index.html) will play the video in new window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because of cookie(document.cookie = e;).
cookie is maintaining the user data as and when user requests for the same resource second time the data already presents in cookie and the same is being sent to the server and hence the server is sending the HTTP 500 Error.